# I still don’t understand how these sentences are interchanged

Tags: sentence-meaning

- I eat too much = I eat food too much
- I eat too much food = I eat too much food

‘Too much’ in the first sentence modifies a verb.

‘Too much’ in the second sentence modifies a noun.

They have certainly different meanings, but how are ‘I eat too much’ and ‘I eat too much food’ able to be interchanged?

https://www.lexico.com/definition/overeat

https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/overeat

Comment: I don't see that these sentences have different meanings. _I eat too much_ implies _too much food_. If you feel lethargic after a big meal, you say "I've eaten too much."

Answer (score 1):

Like many words in English, "much" can function as different parts of speech according to the context.

"Much" can be a determiner, or part of a phrase that forms a determiner like "as much", "this much" or "too much": "We don't have much time",  "I want this much cake",  "He ate too much".

"Much" can also be an adverb: "He is much taller".  "He ate too much".

It is fairly common for determiners to be converted to adverbs by deleting the noun that they determine. And generally it is common for words in English to be changed to other parts of speech without changing their form.  So to understand the grammar of a sentence you need to look at how the words fit together. (Technically, English is an analytic language like Chinese, not a synthetic language like Latin.)

Note that in positive sentences, "much" must modifided by another adverb. So "I ate much" is ungrammatical, but "I ate too much" is correct, and so is "I didn't eat much".